# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client Node.js MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Don't know what's the issue
here is my code.

```
exports.submitAlert = function (req, res) {

    const message = dbConnector.escape(req.body.message);
    const from = dbConnector.escape(req.body.from);
    const to = dbConnector.escape(req.body.to);
    const status = dbConnector.escape(req.body.status);
    const actionType = dbConnector.escape(req.body.action_type);

    if (message == null) res.send(JSON.stringify({
        "success": false,
        "data": null,
        "message": "Please write the message"
    }));

    dbConnector.query('INSERT INTO alert (message, from, to, status, action_type) VALUES (' + message + ', ' + from + ', ' + to + ', ' + status + ', ' + actionType + ');',
        function (err, result) {
        console.log(err);
            if (err) res.send(JSON.stringify({"success": false, "data": null}));

            res.send(JSON.stringify({"success": true, "message": "Alert submitted successfully"}));
        });
};
```

Here is the route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const controller = require('../controllers/alertController');



router.post('/submit', controller.submitAlert);



module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: The problem is, that if there is an error, you are sending `{"success": false, "data": null}` and then `{"success": true, "message": "Alert submitted successfully"}` to the client. You are probably missing an `else`

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that the `res.send` get fired more than once considering your control points. You cannot send more than 1 response to a request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs because if any error comes it'll send the response but after that it'll keeps on executing the code as you're not using the **return** keyword. It'll tell your compiler to stop. I've updated the code have a look. It should work.

```
exports.submitAlert = function (req, res) {

    const message = dbConnector.escape(req.body.message);
    const from = dbConnector.escape(req.body.from);
    const to = dbConnector.escape(req.body.to);
    const status = dbConnector.escape(req.body.status);
    const actionType = dbConnector.escape(req.body.action_type);

    if (message == null) return res.send(JSON.stringify({
        "success": false,
        "data": null,
        "message": "Please write the message"
    }));

    dbConnector.query('INSERT INTO alert (message, from, to, status, action_type) VALUES (' + message + ', ' + from + ', ' + to + ', ' + status + ', ' + actionType + ');',
        function (err, result) {
        console.log(err);
            if (err) return res.send(JSON.stringify({"success": false, "data": null}));

            res.send(JSON.stringify({"success": true, "message": "Alert submitted successfully"}));
        });
};
```

NOTE: another way is to use **else** but you might get callback hell so it's a good practice to use **return** instead.